# Is atom text editor suitable for writing Java programming and android?

Tags: android, atom-editor

I am taking a course on pluralsight.com and I have to study android basics to cross to the next phase of this training.The main focus is to train me to be a google certified mobile web specialist (where the focus of the course is on creating responsive web applications). Can I write android on atom text editor? I might not be needing to write Java/android after this phase of the training hence my question.

Comment: I imagine you will be able to, it won't be very good though. No proper build support, no in ide avd, just missing a lot of features that something like android studio has.

Comment: You can write it in Notepad if you want.  There's nothing magic about a text editor, it just means you'd need to compile from the command line, or find a plugin that does that kind of stuff for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are plugins that will aid the Android development process in Atom, I do not recommend doing so.

Atom is missing a lot of the features of something like Android Studio (which is designed for Android development). You won't have an AVD, code suggestions, etc.

Atom is essentially a fancy text editor and shouldn't be used for Android development since it will just cause you so much more hassle than just installing Android Studio. Especially since you are learning.